# Automation using selenium webdriver to test applet that uploads the file

Tags: selenium-webdriver, applet

I have to automate the test in an application which uses applet for file uploading. I know selenium can not read the elements inside the applet.

Can you please tell me, how this can be done?

[Snapshot of Applet section displayed in WebApp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTkC2.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use sikuli to click on upload button and then use autoit to handle file upload dialog box.

Sikuli Home : http://www.sikuli.org/
AutoIt : http://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/autoit-selenium-webdriver/

Comment: Hello Kalpesh, The issue is, there is no upload button here to open separate file browsing box. The applet is integrated part of web UI. Also, there was no text box like feature, where i could directly add the complete file path. Kindly help.